# How to achieve SSO login into our website with Banno Oauth?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I have this website where Bank users register using API and then Bank can use our SSO login API to log their users directly from Bank's mobile App or website. Now the Bank wants to log into our website via Banno's OAuth. Such that users log into Banno via Bank and then login directly into our website.

How can this be achieved? How will banno know which user to login? How to make it without having users to come into our website and fill user's login details? Can anyone help?

Comment: as Jaime suggested, you need to implement Banno OIDC auth for your website. If you don't want to implement it yourself, we offer a no-code proxy-based solution for that. You just need to install our proxy in front of your website, and our proxy talks to Banno to log user in. https://www.datawiza.com/platform/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your scenario is looking for Banno to be the 'Identity Provider' which is supported by our OAuth + OpenID Connection implementation in our Authentication Framework.

It'll be a good idea to take a look at the [Consumer API OpenID Connect Example](https://github.com/Banno/consumer-api-openid-connect-example) for inspiration.

When you run that example project, you can navigate in your web browser to https://localhost:8080/login.html. That'll show a page with a "Sign in with Banno" button. The page is meant to be a generic representation of what a non-Jack Henry web page would be.

- Imagine that the button was formatted to say "Sign in with [Financial-Institution-name-goes-here]", it would be the same concept.

When you click the "Sign in with Banno" button, you'll be redirected to the *Garden* demo institution. This happens because the example project is configured to begin the authorization flow and use *Garden*.

If you're not signed in as your user in *Garden*, you'll be prompted to sign in.

- It's worth noting that the username + password are never shared back to the example project...the user is logging into their (Banno-powered) financial institution.

After signing in (and accepting the permissions which have been requested), your web browser will be redirected to https://localhost:8080/me which finishes the authentication flow.

- That page then displays the [Identity Token](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/authentication-framework/overview/tokens/#identity-tokens) for your convenience as a developer.
- The content of the Identity Token is usable to cross-reference the user to your existing system and/or to prefill out registration forms.

Hope this helps!